# How to change a parameter value over time?

Tags: omnet++

I need to change the value of a volatile parameter over time in a simulation. I.e. in the first `30s` of the simulation I need `exp(400ms)` after that, until `60s` I need `exp(800ms)` and after `60s exp(2s)` for `interArrivalTime`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For volatile parameters there is a pretty easy trick. Use the `? :` operator along with the `simTime()` NED function:

```
**.interArrivalTime = simTime() < 30s ? exponetntial(400ms) : exponential(800ms)
```

or you can even chain them as ?: operator is evaluated left to right:

```
**.interArrivalTime = exponential(simTime() < 30s ? 400ms : simTime() < 60s ? 800ms : 2s)
```

would give:

- `exponential(400ms)` below `30s`
- `exponential(800ms)` between `30` and `60s`
- `exponential(2s)` after `60s`